# changing the order of some element(index) in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an array that was put together by  a push method. The elements that were pushed into the array were taken from different divs. now the array is ordered by the way they appear on the dom. I would like to change the order of some of the element so a class attribute could be applied to a new order one at a time through a newly ordered array.

I will show you the [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/MKZvq/) that has a class added and removed moving along an array. The thing is I have these parent divs layed out by using floats to look like they make a pic frame  where the children divs are clickable and content appears inside the frame.( not shown in jsfiddle)

when the added class appears at the end of the right part of the frame it goes to the beginning of the bottom row of divs, which is the bottom part of the frame but i want it to start with the last div of the bottom row ]so it continues travelling through out the frame like a clock. I do not have the frame set up in the jsfiddle I just need to how to cahnge the order so i could apply the classes in that order.

Heres the array now

```
index :0 =prt1
index :1 =prt2
index :2 =prt3
index :3 =prt4
index :4 =prl5
index :5 =prl6
index :6 =prl7
index :7 =prl8
index :8 =prr9
index :9 =prr10
index :10 =prr11
index :11 =prr12
index :12 =prb13
index :13 =prb14
index :14 =prb15
index :15 =prb16
```

I want the order of the array to be:

```
index :0 =prt1
index :1 =prt2
index :2 =prt3
index :3 =prt4 //top right corner
index :4 =prl5
index :5 =prl6
index :6 =prl7
index :7 =prl8 
index :11 =prr12 //botttom right corner the order has to change or the flashing div will    not follow the clock pattern
index :10 =prr11
index :9 =prr10
index :8 =prr9 //bottom left corner
index :15 =prb16
index :14 =prb15
index :13 =prb14
index :12 =prb13
```

I need a lesson in changing the order of a group of indexes inside an array so i could apply a function to this new order. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you know the exact order you want and assuming there's no sorting algorithm you can create that would later be useful you can just hard-code it like so:

```
var desiredOrder = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,11,10,9,8,15,14,13,12];
var orderedArray = [];
for(key in desiredOrder){
    orderedArray.push(existingArray[desiredOrder[key]]);
}
existingArray=orderedArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a combination of slice, reverse and concat would be the best here:

```
newArr = oldArr.slice(0,8).concat(oldArr.slice(8,4).reverse())
                                         .concat(oldArr.slice(12,4).reverse());
```

Comment: thanks I never used .concat() before  and slice like this. but I copied and pasted this substituting aldArr with my arr and it didn't work but thanks for sharing it gave me ideas.